# 500 internal server error, http post by angularjs

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, http, laravel

I try to do ajax using angularjs but I get 500 internal server error in console.

**angular**

```
$scope.submit = function(){

$http.post('shop', {'order_list':  JSON.stringify($scope.order_list)})
  .success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  });

}
```

**Laravel's Controller**

```
public function addtocart(){

    OrderList::unguard();

    $order_list_input = json_decode(Input::get('order_list'));
    $order_list = new OrderList;
    $order_list->order_id =1;
    $order_list->product_id = $order_list_input->product_id;
    $order_list->amount = $order_list_input->amount;
    $order_list->total_cost = Prod::find($order_list_input->product_id)->price * $order_list_input->amount;
    $order_list->save(); //works when I comment this line out.

    var_dump($order_list_input);

}
```

I don't get it. I just comment out that line and it works.

**Laravel's Model**

```
class OrderList extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'order_lists';
    protected $fillable = array('order_id','product_id','amount','total_cost');

    public function order_list_attribute() {
         return $this->hasMany('Order_list_attribute');
    }

    public function product(){
        return $this->hasOne('Prod');
    }


}
```

Thank's for your help :D

Comment: Ehh - then that `save()` function is probably failing with a server error..what is it?

Comment: Try using `try` and `catch` blocks to see what's going on, perhaps? @tymeJV: the save() method is a Laravel DB method.

Comment: or turn on error reporting. 
`error_reporting(E_ALL &~E_NOTICE)`

Comment: You are putting some bad information into the database.  My first guess is you set `order_id` as primary key or auto increments or unique and it's having trouble trying to set it as 1.

Comment: order_id is foreign key.